# Why does analysing mirrored children against the Type of generic function parameters produce nil results?

Tags: swift, generics, types

In the below example both `classInstance` and `structInstance` are `nil`. Why is this please?

```
let reflector = Reflector()
let classInstance = reflector.get(thing: MyClass.self)
let structInstance = reflector.get(thing: MyStruct.self)

class MyClass {}
struct MyStruct {}

class Reflector {
    let mc: MyClass
    let ms: MyStruct

    init() {
        mc = MyClass()
        ms = MyStruct()
    }

    func get<T>(thing: T) -> T? {
        let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)
        for (_, child) in mirror.children.enumerated() {
            if let t = child.value as? T {
                return t
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Your parameter should be `T.Type`

Comment: What package are you using? `Reflector` is not a class in the Standard Library or Foundation

Comment: Thanks @dan. If you want to add that as an official answer I'd be happy to accept it. It would also be useful to have a short explanation as to why it needs to be T.Type, if you have the time. No drama if not, thanks for the help anyway